# Arquivo hbs não redenriza

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com **backend** *Node.js* e *Handlebars*. Estou tendo dificuldade pra renderizar o arquivo **layout.hbs**, já fiz alguns testes nos arquivos **server.js** e **main.js** e as rotas estão ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Realtime Twitter</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="/css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Meu projeto completo no [GitHub](https://github.com/lobothiagodev/NodejsWorkstation/tree/master/twitter).

Dependências

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "hbs": "^4.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.7",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0"
  }
```

Comment: Não está carregando o layout porque vc não está importando ou chamando ele em nenhum lugar. Sua rota main carrega somente main/landing.hbs. Se você quer carregar as demais views, como layout ou navbar, vc precisa indicar

Comment: server.js
app.engine('.hbs', express({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const mainRoutes = require('./routes/main');

app.use(mainRoutes);

Comment: main.js
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('main/landing');

});

module.exports = router;

Comment: Ah ok, tente `defaultLayout: 'layouts/layout'` Apach3

Comment: Não deu certo app.engine('.hbs', express({ defaultLayout: 'layouts/layout', extname: '.hbs' }));

Engraçado que não retorna nenhum erro, a pagina so fica em branco.

Comment: Ia te chamar no chat pra não ficarmos na tentativa e erro aqui, mas voce nao tem privilegio ainda. tente inserir isso https://jsfiddle.net/vu4kn4nf/

Comment: Então a melhor solução é largar hbs de mão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema encontra-se na linha abaixo em seu arquivo **serve.js**:

```
app.engine('.hbs', express({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs' }));
```

Segundo a [documentação](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/guide/using-template-engines.html), ao setar a configuração `view engine` você deve informar como parâmetro um **Mecanismo de modelo** o que no caso você não esta fazendo, pois você esta informando o próprio **Express**. Apenas altere **express** para **expressHbs** como no código abaixo.

```
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout',extname: '.hbs'}));
```

#### Referência

- [Usando mecanismos de modelo com o Express](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Comment: Resolvido! obrigado pelo link.

Comment: Por nada, apenas considere marcar como aceita clicando no **✅** verde.